# Move all indicators to the left side so that window buttons can be placed in the corner

Tags: indicator, gnome-shell

I'd like to move my indicators to the left side of the top bar as I'm using the 'Pixel saver' extension, which removes the titles from windows and moves the 'minimize-maximize-exit' buttons to the top bar.

The indicators make them float next to them, that's why I'd like to move them to the left corner (before 'Activities').
[image: Current topbar with weird window buttons]

Is this possible? Is the indicator button hardcoded?

Comment: it is called aggregate menu and yes it is hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first plan was to move the aggregate menu to the left so my window buttons would sit in the corner.

As it's hard coded, I set the window buttons to the left and used '*[Hide Activities Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/744/hide-activities-button/)*' extension for GNOME shell, as the Activities button was in the way. Now the window control buttons are in a corner.